# question about reading an input using fgets and scanf in c

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I have recently been trying to do an exercise in c.

I want to read the input which is something like: "SET 0" (note that the actual text will be parsed later).

I tried fgets as it is like that:

```
char in[20];
//ok, this reads the first line, the first input is meant to be a number
scanf("%s",in);

if(isdigit(in[0])){

    char array[]={'?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?'};

    auto counter = atoi(in);

    while(counter !=0){

        fgets(in, sizeof(in),stdin);
```

For some reason, when i type eg "SET 0" and i am using fgets the in variable is empty(will print nothing).

I tried scanf but it will not read the number.

Any ideas/suggestions of what i can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `auto counter = atoi(in);` It's funny how it just works here, but I believe `auto` doesn't mean what you think it does. `what i can do?` What do you want to do? What should the result be? I don't understand, what exactly have you tried? How did you check if `in` variable is empty after using `fgets`? How did you use `fgets`? Did you check `fgets` return value?

Comment: If the input is 'SET 0', then scanf will set `in` to the string "SET".  So `isdigit(in[0])` is false.

Comment: Konstantinosm Are you using a [C++ compiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)?

Comment: Never do `scanf("%s", ...)`. It is unsafe and probably doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `fgets()` with `scanf()` until you know why scanf()` is evil.

`fgets()` read the left over `'\n'` of the first line of user input which `scanf()` did not read.